# Unable to start Internet Explorer or Chrome in Selenium Webdriver (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to start up an IE instance using Webdriver.  I can't figure out why I'm receiving these errors, my code appears to be identical to every example I can find on the web.
I'm using Java and testng.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Tests {

    File file = new File("C:\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath() );  
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
```

The following errors are displaying, all of these errors are on the "System.setProperty" line.

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ""webdriver.ie.driver"", invalid 
     FormalParameterList
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    - Syntax error on tokens, FormalParameter expected instead

Please note that I have the exact same problem if I try to use Chrome with this code:

```
File file = new File("C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Did you try to set the system property also as command line argument with ```-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe"```?

Comment: @luksch - Just tried using that argument with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your code from inside class instead of running it from inside method. Covert it to something like

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // <-- you need a method!
       File file = new File("C:\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath() );  
       WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you JacekM,  moving those codes inside a method removes the errors.  Will I now have to instantiate the IE driver in every method in my test suite?  I have already created all my test cases(methods) using firefox driver.  For firefox I just had the driver instantiated in the class before my methods and it worked great.

Comment: Not necessarily. You need to set property with driver path only once, so you can do it before executing the rest of methods in test suite. You can then create ChromeDriver or InternetExplorerDriver the same way you create FirefoxDriver. However sharing browsers across different test methods is not recommended. In addition I would recommend using some kind of test framework (JUnit or TestNG) - that would help you with instantiating browser.

Comment: @SteveA If you are using TestNG then you can set driver paths (System.setProperty(...)) in `@BeforeSuite` method and instantiate browser in `@BeforeMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

I'm using "mvn test" to lunch the test process so the path of the IE driver may be changed

```
File file = new File("classes/tools/IEDriverServer.exe");
```

Use IE driver with Capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
caps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

It may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, on the updated eclipse version, you might have to use @suppressWarnings

```
package Login;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

       File file = new File("C:\\Users\\IEDRiverServer.exe");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath() );  

       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

       } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
public class IE {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Sathish\\soft\\SELENIUM\\LatestDownloads\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.get("www.google.com");
            driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("abc");
            driver.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do the below process.

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("InternetExplorer")) {

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
caps.setCapability(    InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                    true);

caps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
browser = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);

Then after, In IE, from the Tools menu (or the gear icon in the toolbar in later versions), select "Internet options." Go to the Security tab. At the bottom of the dialog for each zone, you should see a check box labeled "Enable Protected Mode." Set the value of the check box to the same value, 
either checked or unchecked, for each zone.

I have applied the same thing at my end, it works fine.