# Selenium code not identifying the webelements on IE10

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium code doesn't identifying the webelements on IE10. Even after the path is set for the driver.

```
File file = new File("D:\\Driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
dr=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: Care to share more details? What kind of elements does it not identify? With what error? All the time? Intermittently? Have you set the protected mode settings? What version of Selenium? What version of the IEDriver? What version of Windows? Are the elements in an IFrame? Same issue in Chrome?

Comment: information in not enough.did you get what kind of error?check this link..it might be help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386594/unable-to-start-internet-explorer-or-chrome-in-selenium-webdriver-java

Comment: No elements are identified.Browser is launched and the application is opened but the text elements are not identified. I'm using windows 8.The elements are not in iframe.The code is working for firefox, chrome and as well as safari

Comment: Did you check the browser zoom level? It should be 100% as per the Selenium WIKI: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Comment: Yes the zoom level is 100%

Comment: What error are you getting?! The **full** error and stack trace! Share the code and error you are using!!

Comment: Have you configured the same protected modes for all of the security items in internet properties?  The checkbox has to match for all 4 otherwise WebDriver loses the window after it opens.  There are also settings for starting a clean session.

Please provide more information...

Comment: Thanks @mutt and arran the protection mode was supposed to be enabled

Comment: @jeevz: This question seems to describe a valid problem, but much of the relevant information is hidden in the comments. Please edit the question body (and possibly also the title) so that it contains all relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the same protected modes for all of the security items in internet properties.  The checkboxes must match for all 4 otherwise WebDriver loses the window after it opens.